# How to call array to another method?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web-services, soap

I am trying to calculate barter system so first I m adding the items to Inventory(json file) another method... then   trying to calculate min max price array in CalCost method and send to howmuch method like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public double[] CalInstrumentCost(String instrumentName, double instrumentQuantity)
    {
        double[] priv = new double[2];

        try
        {

            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            MusicInstrumentsList Mlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MusicInstrumentsList>(jsonString);
            var MInstrument = Mlist.MusicInstruments_List.Find(item => item.InstrumentsName == instrumentName);

            if (MInstrument != null)
            {

                double miprice = MInstrument.MinInstrumentPrice * instrumentQuantity;
                double maPrice = MInstrument.MaxInstrumentPrice * instrumentQuantity;

                priv[0] = miprice; // min Price
                priv[1] = maPrice; // max Price


                return priv;  
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Operation");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Operation");
        }
    }
```

but priv doesn't exist so I tried define globally but calculating is INF (1/0 = ınf) what can I do ?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public double HowMuchInstrument(String instrumentName, double totalBudget)
    {
        double result = 0;



        try
        {
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            MusicInstrumentsList Mlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MusicInstrumentsList>(jsonString);
            var MInstrument = Mlist.MusicInstruments_List.Find(item => item.InstrumentsName == instrumentName);

            if (MInstrument != null)
            {
                result = Math.Floor(totalBudget / priv[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create `priv` inside `CalInstrumentCost()` so it is not visible outside.

You can add additional parameter to `HowMuchInstrument()` and call `CalInstrumentCost()` inside (if this method is in the same class):

```
// instrumentQuantity parameter added (do you really need double and not int ?)
[WebMethod]
public double HowMuchInstrument(String instrumentName, double instrumentQuantity, double totalBudget)
{
    double result = 0;

    try
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        MusicInstrumentsList Mlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MusicInstrumentsList>(jsonString);
        var MInstrument = Mlist.MusicInstruments_List.Find(item => item.InstrumentsName == instrumentName);
         
        // here you call method to make needed calculations and store result in local variable
        var priv = CalInstrumentCost(instrumentName, instrumentQuantity);

        if (MInstrument != null)
        {
            result = Math.Floor(totalBudget / priv[0]); // no error here anymore
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

1. the type of `instrumentQuantity` is `double` - can't be `int`?
2. you use array in `CalInstrumentCost()` to store min and max values - you can just create separate class with 2 properties and you don't need to rely on positions in array
3. if you need better precision you can use `decimal` instead of `double`